# Prior dev, instead of changing CSS files just wrote another on top. Now I have to migrate those changes to the actual files - any suggestions?

Tags: regex, search, replace

Any ideas on how to most effectively search and replace or perhaps merge the files. I would do it by hand but the core files are fragmented and there's allot of them.

I was thinking of using Gulp search and replace.

For instance one of the edits include

```
.compi, .compi + #node {
  margin: 0;
 padding: 40px 30px;
 clear: both;
}
```

The original is

```
.compi {
  margin: 0px 20px 0 20px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming just including the new "scratch" CSS files after the originals is not an option?

Comment: Yeah, so the orginal files were modularised for maximum efficiency and for whatever reason the developer decided not to use that and just mass overwrite everything. Lazy and easy way out. Now I'm stuck with hundreds of duplicated css code lines making the whole thing unbearably slow.